# Cannot run program "make": The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

This is the first time that this error has come up. I am using Cygwin with Eclipse 3.5 and my Path variable is set to: `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Apache Ant\bin;C:\Program Files\SVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;C:\Users\Mohit\Developer\AndroidSDK\tools;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\cygwin\bin` Notice that `C:\cygwin\bin` is in my Path. And make.exe is is my Cygwin bin. So I think the problem is not with my system, but maybe my project. But I can't find anything wrong with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you have run "make" on the command line?

Comment: @TofuBeer What do you mean? Does "make" register on the command line? Or does "make" build the project from the command line?

Comment: TofuBeer means "What happens when you type make as a command?"  Do you get the same cannot run program error, do you get a different error, what?

Comment: Moheit, mpez0 is exactly right.  If the command doesn't run on the command line then it won't run elsewhere.  Also did you restart eclipse after you changed the PATH?

Comment: @mepz0, TofuBeer It does run on the command line just fine actually. But not in Eclipse (even after I restarted it).

Comment: No idea then... I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: Are you trying to use `make` to compile a Java program? The standard tool for building Java projects is Apache Ant, try using that instead: http://ant.apache.org/

Comment: @Jesper No, I am using eclispe CDT and trying to compile C.

Comment: PLEASE STATE A REASON WHY YOU VOTED DOWN!!!!!

Comment: +1 exactly same problem.  I don't know where and when the hell eclipse  goes and edits this PATH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to take a look at the PATH environment variable inside Eclipse's process.  It's possible that it's changing its PATH internally -- if that's the case, you'll need to figure out how to configure Eclipse so that its PATH is set up correctly.

If you're finding that `C:\cygwin\bin` isn't in Eclipse's PATH, and you recently added that to your PATH, you need to close and restart Eclipse for that change to take affect.

If you still can't figure it out, try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a filter for Eclipse.exe to get a long, detailed listing of everything it's trying to do.  Look for the call to `CreateProcess()` that's failing and see if you can learn anything more.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I solved that copy make.exe file in path that ecilipse given.
from link below
http://www.mediafire.com/download/e9j9g4zun2t68jn/make.exe
hope helps

Answer (score 0):

I go around this issue by installing MinGW and use its GCC compiler.

Environment - OS: Windows 10, Eclipse: Oxygen